# What is the required lifetime of objects returned by import() and exect_file()?

Tags: boost-python

Below is a condensed form of this example: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/python/doc/v2/exec.html#examples

Python function to call from C++, stored in the file *script.py*:

```
def greet():
   return 'Hello from Python!'
```

The C++ code to execute the Python function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

void greet()
{ 
  object main = import("__main__");
  object global(main.attr("__dict__"));
  object result = exec_file("script.py", global, global);
  object greet = global["greet"];
  std::string message = extract<std::string>(greet());
  std::cout << message << std::endl;
}
```

My question is: **do I need to keep the *main*, *global* and *result* objects alive to be able to call *greet*?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't. Everything that needs to be alive is kept alive by references held by the `greet` object, you don't need to hold objects around yourself.

Comment: Could you cite a source please?

Comment: @spaceknarf I tested it with the `main`, `global`, and `result` objects destroyed, it worked, and valgrind had no (additional) complaints.